# How to fix button width in tkinter if I want to put text in it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I tried to put some text in a button. But the pre-set size changed, to the text's size

so this is the code:

```py
frame = tk.Frame(master=gridframe, width=15, height=15, borderwidth=0, bg=mzcolor)
frame.grid(row=1, column=1)
button = tk.Button(master=frame, text=f"●", font=("System", 10), width=15, height= 15, fg="black", bg="red", relief=tk.RIDGE)
button.pack()
```

So how can I keep the pre-set sizes? Any Ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by *"pre-set size"*?

Comment: @acw1668 like width, height

Comment: You have already specified such options, so what is the problem actually?

Comment: @acw1668 so there are a grid, where there are `frame`s. and inside the frames, there are buttons, with text. but when I try to put this text inside the buttons, it dont want to fill the existing area